# MySQLi event delete row after certain time

Tags: php, events, mysqli, where-clause, verification

I want users on my page to verify thier accounts (email) in one day. If a user isn't verified yet the datetime (date) is set to something like ***0000***-03-23 15:45:56 (the year is 0000 - I know that this causes problems in new years eve).

**Event:** (every hour)

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE SUBSTR(date, 0, 4)='0000' AND DAY(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), date)) >= 1
```

The event isn't working so i've created this **test query**:

```
$resultOne = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM users WHERE SUBSTR(date, 0, 4)='0000'")or die($mysqli->error);
$resultTwo = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM users WHERE DAY(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), date)) >= 1")or die($mysqli->error);
```

Now i'm getting this error message:

> Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause'

**Questions:**

- Why isn't it working?
- Which better ways to verify users do you recomment?

**Thank you!** *- Minding*

Comment: Use date column  in backtick ` date `

Comment: I get no error, but not verified users aren't showed. I don't want date to be a string. (It's a table field)

Comment: backticks are really handy if you want to have column names like count, type, table or similar – i mean for reserved keyword of mysql

Comment: The column does not exist by that name. I have run the same query on my pc and it works `DELETE FROM brand_contact_history WHERE SUBSTR( brand_number, 0, 4 ) =  '0000' AND DAY( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , brand_number ) ) >=1` although I'm not sure of the event thing.

Comment: I've change the name to "myDate" but the test query still throws the same error message (i've also change the field name to "myDate") :(

Comment: The problem was this "SHOW COLUMNS" I've changed it to "SELECT *" and now it's working, but the event is still not working.

Comment: I solved it, answer incoming :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there where two problems here:

**First: test query**

The "SHOW COLUMNS" didn't accept my where clause, but "SELECT *" did.

**Second: SUBSTR()**

I don't know exectly why, but the MySQLi SUBSTR has to be:

```
SUBSTR(date, 1, 4)='0000'
```

Not like in PHP:

```
substr($user['date'], 0, 4) === '0000'
```

**One last problem:**

New users are deleted nearly instantly (every hour -> test: every minute) and not after 1 day as they should.

**EDIT:**

I just want to share my final event code, in case somebody needs it:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE SUBSTR(date, 1, 4)='0000' AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), CONCAT(SUBSTR(NOW(), 1, 5), SUBSTR(date, 5)))) >= 24
```

**Thank you** all for your comments! *- Minding*